# html component can't work when webview（android） reload html component again

Tags: android, webview, enter

first time when i dynamic "vamp up" strings to a well-formed html.webview it worked well, including `<input = 'text'`, but the next time the same webview doesn't work, especially `<input = 'text'`

When one touches it, the keyboard appears, but one can not enter any word.

The webView setting is as follows:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new runJavaScript(), "myjs");
webView.requestFocus();
webView.requestFocusFromTouch();
```

This only happens in SDK 2.0.1 & 2.1-update.

Answer (score 0):

I got it.  in xml file add linealayout,not webview , when make up html new webview ,new webview in java code, then add on linealayout, of couse linealayout removeallview first.